# ¿Porqué no puedo enviar mails con otro remitente?

Tags: php, mail

Tengo un problema con una aplicación con la que envío mails con encuestas y la misma aplicación tiene la posibilidad de escoger el remitente pero si este correo no contiene el dominio donde está alojada esta App, por ejemplo remitente@example.com y ejemplo@midominio.com, el primer mail no está alojado y no usa el mismo dominio.

¿Cómo podría resolver este problema?

Este es el código que uso para el envio de mails

```
require_once('mail/Mail.php');
    require_once('Mail/mime.php');

    $from = $remitente;
    $to = $destinatario;
    $subject = $asunto;

        $text = 'This is a text message.';
        $crlf = "\n";  
        // Creating the Mime message
        $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);

        // Setting the body of the email
        $mime->setTXTBody($text);
        $mime->setHTMLBody($html);

    $host = "mail.midominio.com";
    $smtpPort = '587';

    $username = "contact@midominio.com";
    $password = "*********";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
      'To' => $to,
      'Subject' => $subject,
        'Content-Type'  => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    );
    $mime_params = array(
      'text_encoding' => '7bit',
      'text_charset'  => 'UTF-8',
      'html_charset'  => 'UTF-8',
      'head_charset'  => 'UTF-8'
    );

    $body = $mime->get($mime_params);
    $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
      array ('host' => $host,
        'port' => $smtpPort,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password));

    $envio = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);   

    if (PEAR::isError($envio)) {
      // CON ERRORES
      $errores = 1;
     } else {
        // MAIL CORRECTO
     }
```

Comment: Puedes enviar correos con cualquier email menos de vacío o email mal formado. Qué error tienes? Qué valores tiene $remitente? Creo que al momento de enviar el correo puede ser que llega vacío.

Comment: La variable `$remitente` si obtiene el valor correspondiente porque si envio como remitente `ejemplo@midominio.com` si funciona pero si el remitente es `ejemplo@otrodominio.com` no funciona.

Comment: Es propio tu servidor de correo o está alojada en algún host?

Comment: Está alojado en un host.He hablado con ellos y me han comentado que solo hay como solución añadir estos correos al servidor o desde ese dominio añadir unos registros pero necesito saber si hay otro método más eficiente.

Comment: Intenta sin el host y el Puerto, yo lo tengo sin eso, ya que si está alojada en el host debe funcionar sin esos parámetros.

Comment: Envía el correo con la cuenta de tu dominio y agrega el otro correo como `reply-to` para evitar que sea enviado directo a no deseado o que sea descartado.

Comment: He probado de quitar el host y el puerto @Bicho pero me salta un error conforme estos valores estan vacios ya que en mi código hago uso de este host para poder enviar los mails.